# AIX and daemon service

Tags: aix, daemon, init, sysvinit, start-stop-daemon

I see that the daemon service is started and stopped via the commands:

startsrc and stopsrc on group/subsystem.

I have init.d script and I want to make it daemon service in AIX.
From these commands I think I have to put the init.d script into a group 
and then the starting and stopping of the service will be done by 
the commands "startsrc" and "stopsrc" executed on the group/subsystem.But how can I put the init.d script into a group/subsystem?

Comment: Examine `/etc/rc.d/rc2` for samples.

Comment: Yes, my scripts looks just like a script from /etc/rc.d/rc2 but how should i use it with the "startsrc" and "stopsrc" commands?

Comment: Sorry, that I don't know. But at least you can do these: `/etc/rc.d/init.d/homemade start` and `/etc/rc.d/init.d/homemade stop`. These would work in other Unix versions, too.

Answer (score 2):

> I have init.d script

Don't start from there, especially if it came from a non-AIX system.  This is almost certainly rubbish that will lead you up the garden path.

Just plonking an `rc` script under the service manager is a sin that people commit on Linux operating systems using systemd, but it has been a sin for a *long* time, especially on AIX, which has had proper service management since 1990.

Use the `mkssys` command to define your subsystem, which you can then start and stop as you said with `startsrc` and `stopsrc`.  Use the `rmssys` to remove it if you ever want to do that.  Use the `-s` option to all of these with a unique name for your subsystem.

You more probably than not want `-S` with `mkssys`, and `-R`.  Just work out the command path and arguments for your dæmon process, and the user ID it is to run as, and employ the `-p`, `-a`, `-u` options appropriately.

Your `rc` script will give you a clue as to the command path and arguments, but that will probably be buried under a heap of shell variables and stuff.  That's probably the only information in the `rc` script that will be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks , I was also wondering when we create mkssys entry let's call it , "mySysEntry" and start it via  startsrc -s mySysEntry -a "start" the service starts indeed, however "lssrc -a" shows that mySysEntry is not operational, how can I make lssrc -a to show that the service is active?

Comment: IBM's mkssys documentation: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=m-mkssys-command