# exec command not evaluating properly

Tags: shell-script

From a shell script I am executing this:

```
exec "su - $PRODUCT_USER -c 'CATALINA_PID=\"$CATALINA_PID\" \"$CATALINA_RUN_SCRIPT\" start'"
```

and I get as an error in the console

```
./runService.sh[10]: su - testUser -c 'CATALINA_PID="/home/tomcat.pid" "/home/subScript.sh" start':  not found.
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `eval` instead of `exec`? You don't need to quote the whole command to be a single word with `exec`. Just do `exec su - ....`

Comment: Thanks, it worked, however now I get the message that "The specified path name is too long."

Comment: I sense the House of Horror again.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564427/5132  And abuse of `su`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353698/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465353/5132